# Unknown error on optimizing CNN on Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, bayesian

I want to optimize my CNN as [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/deep-learning-using-bayesian-optimization.html) using `Bayesian optimization` and `Matlab 2019a`. Instead of showing whole my codes in a single part, I split it to three parts to show which lines causes error. First part is about loading data, dividing for training and validation and defining optimization variables. **Second part is where error is**. Third part is remaining part of codes. Note that `buildLayer` is also written by me to make network layers.

My questions are: 
 how can I fix aforementioned error and why it occurred?

First part is (loading data):

```
folder = 'C:\Users\X';
imds = imageDatastore(folder, ...
"IncludeSubfolders",true, ...
"LabelSource","foldernames");

num = 20;
per = randperm(1000, num);
figure;
for i=1 : num
    subplot(4, 5, i);
    imshow(imds.Files{per(i)});
end

img = readimage(imds,1);

[trainData, validData] = splitEachLabel(imds,0.8);

% defining optimizable variables
optVars = [
    optimizableVariable('depth', [1 5], "Type","integer")
    optimizableVariable('initLearningRate', [0.001, 1], "Transform","log")
    optimizableVariable('initFilterNum', [8 32], "Type","integer")
    optimizableVariable('momentum', [0.7 0.98])
    optimizableVariable('l2Reg', [1e-10 1e-2],'Transform','log')]

objFcn = makeObjFcn(trainData,validData);
```

I get this error:

> Array formation and parentheses-style indexing with objects of class
>   'matlab.io.datastore.ImageDatastore' is not allowed.  Use objects of
>   class 'matlab.io.datastore.ImageDatastore' only as scalars or use a
>   cell array.
>
> Error in unique>uniqueR2012a (line 191)
>       a = a(:);
>
> Error in unique (line 103)
>       [varargout{1:nlhs}] = uniqueR2012a(varargin{:});
>
> Error in main>makeObjFcn/valErrorFun (line 47)
>           numClasses = numel(unique(vaData));
>
> Error in BayesianOptimization/callObjNormally (line 2560)
>                           [Objective, ConstraintViolations, UserData] = this.ObjectiveFcn(conditionalizeX(this, X));
>
> Error in BayesianOptimization/callObjFcn (line 467)
>                       = callObjNormally(this, X);
>
> Error in BayesianOptimization/runSerial (line 1989)
>                       ObjectiveFcnObjectiveEvaluationTime, ObjectiveNargout] = callObjFcn(this, this.XNext);
>
> Error in BayesianOptimization/run (line 1941)
>                   this = runSerial(this);
>
> Error in BayesianOptimization (line 457)
>               this = run(this);
>
> Error in bayesopt (line 323) Results = BayesianOptimization(Options);

on second part (the lines cause error):

```
bayesObj = bayesopt(...
    objFcn, optVars, ...
    "MaxTime", 1* 3600,...,
    "IsObjectiveDeterministic",false,...
    "UseParallel",false);
```

and third part (remaining of codes):

```
estIdx = bayesObj.IndexOfMinimumTrace(end);
fileName = bayesObj.UserDataTrace{bestIdx};
savedStruct = load(fileName);
valError = savedStruct.valError;


function ObjFcn = makeObjFcn(trData,vaData)
ObjFcn = @valErrorFun;
    function [valError,cons,fileName] = valErrorFun(optVars)

        % making layers
        imageSize = [32 32 3];
        numClasses = numel(unique(vaData));
        layers = buidLayers(...
            imageSize,... 
            optVars.initFilterNum,...
            optVars.depth,...
            numClasses);

        miniBatchSize = 256;
        validationFrequency = floor(numel(vaData)/miniBatchSize);
        options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
            'InitialLearnRate',optVars.initLearningRate, ...
            'Momentum',optVars.momentum1, ...
            'MaxEpochs',60, ...
            'LearnRateSchedule','piecewise', ...
            'LearnRateDropPeriod',40, ...
            'LearnRateDropFactor',0.1, ...
            'MiniBatchSize',miniBatchSize, ...
            'L2Regularization',optVars.l2Reg, ...
            'Shuffle','every-epoch', ...
            'Verbose',false, ...
            'Plots','training-progress', ...
            'ValidationData',vaData, ...
            'ValidationFrequency',validationFrequency);

        pixelRange = [-4 4];

        imageAugmenter = imageDataAugmenter( ...
            'RandXReflection',true, ...
            'RandXTranslation',pixelRange, ...
            'RandYTranslation',pixelRange);
        datasource = augmentedImageDatastore(...
            imageSize,...
            trData,...
            'DataAugmentation',imageAugmenter);

        trainedNet = trainNetwork(datasource,layers,options);
        %close(findall(groot,'Tag','NNET_CNN_TRAININGPLOT_FIGURE'))

        YPredicted = classify(trainedNet,XValidation);
        valError = 1 - mean(YPredicted == YValidation);

        fileName = num2str(valError) + ".mat";
        save(fileName,'trainedNet','valError','options')
        cons = [];

    end
end
```